# Installing h2o on Databricks under R: jsonlite error message:

Tags: r, databricks, h2o, jsonlite

I am trying to install h2o (R version) on Databricks.

I started with the following:

```
%sh
apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev -y
apt-get update -y
apt-get install -y r-cran-jsonlite
```

It all ran fine. Then I tried:

```
install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos=(c("http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable_R")))
```

but got back the following error:

```
Warning message:
This project is configured to use R version '4.0.4', but '4.2.2' is currently being used. 
ERROR: dependency ‘jsonlite’ is not available for package ‘h2o’
* removing ‘/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/rEnv-2a5edebe-8ede-4459-8a8b-72c0047b8a01/h2o’
Installing package into ‘/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/rEnv-2a5edebe-8ede-4459-8a8b-72c0047b8a01’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable_R/src/contrib/h2o_3.40.0.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-tar' length 177590345 bytes (169.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 169.4 MB

Warning in utils::install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
  installation of package ‘h2o’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpXqq9V0/downloaded_packages’
```

What is the best way to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 2):

You could also try setting multiple repositories, e.g.

```
options(repos = c(
 h2o = "http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable_R",
 CRAN = "https://cloud.r-project.org"
))

install.packages("h2o", type="source")
```

This way, R can find the `h2o` package on its own repository, and install any dependencies from the regular CRAN repository.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to install the R package jsonlite.

Comment: Ty!, I thought I did it with `apt-get install -y r-cran-jsonlite`?